# Problem in CreateProcess function!

Tags: c, process, multithreading, createprocess

I have my main application ,from my main application I will be calling another
module(third party) to perform a small operation in my main application,when I call that module..it processes for a particular time say 5 sec.while its proccessing it shows the process in the commmand window with some information..now my main application waits until the called module finishes its process.Now my Question is..how to do I hide this command window without disturbing its process..I tried to use the createprocess but it seems to not work...

for example: my main application is the Parent process and the called application is child process..Parent process should be independent of the child process..check my example below

```
int main()
{
  execl("c:\\users\\rakesh\\Desktop\\calledapplication.exe","c:\\users\\rakesh\\Desktop    \\calledapplication.exe",0);


}

code in calledapplication
int main
{
  printf("Rakesh");
}
```

now considering the above if you run the first program...output would appear in the same 
command window(It shouldnt be like that)...I want the main application to create the process but it should not be affected by child process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in the `dwCreationFlags` parameter of `CreateProcess`.

Comment: @Rakesh - having no console window displayed for a process is quite a different request than somehow forcing a program to not be able to display a message box it's programmed to display. You should clarify in your question exactly what you're trying to do so people aren't guessing or solving the wrong problem

Answer (score 1):

You talked about a "command window", so I presume that the child is a console application.
In that case you can create the process in a separate conole and optionally force the new console to be iconified or hidden.
The following code launch a child process that interprets a batch file (mytest.bat).
I hope it can help. Regards.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
BOOL rv = FALSE;
WCHAR cmdline[] = TEXT("cmd.exe /c mytest.bat");

    memset(&si,0,sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
// Add this if you want to hide or minimize the console
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; //or SW_MINIMIZE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    memset(&pi,0,sizeof(pi));
    rv = CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL,
                           FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                           NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    if (rv) {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
                printf("Done! :)\n");
    }
        else {
                printf("Failed :(\n");

    }

        return rv ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: I've tried so many methods and examples to hide my flashing cmd.exe window (i run the cmd  with parameters), and currently have 12 browser tabs open with only stackoverflow pages about ShellExecute, ShellExecuteEx and CreateProcess. Nothing appears to work for me and i'm afraid to post a question for it, since there's already so much to read about. Still i have to throw this out for the sake of my well being (this is my second day of trying but my hopes are nearing its end). I've never imagined something "simple" as hiding a cmd.exe window with arguments would be such a pain to do with c++ ...

Comment: Does my sample code work in your environment, e.g. by having only "@echo off" in "mytest.bat? (By the way, what system/architecture are you using?)

Comment: Hi Giuseppe: Thank you for your time responding to me. My working environment is Windows 10 x64 - Actually i'm not using the code to call/exec an external .bat, but to hide the cmd.exe window when its being called with arguments: https://ghostbin.com/paste/a9sek . But, even when using ShellExecute(Ex) i can't manage to hide the flashing window. I know there are other ways/workarounds for this i.e. vbs (Windows Scripting Host) but i really want to do this using c++ . Unfortunately, non of the posted answers/solutions on StackOverflow (or any other site) have helped me in that regard :-(

Comment: In your example at line 20 there is "memset(&si,0,sizeof(pi));", this clears the settings in "si". I presume you would have written "memset(&pi,0,sizeof(pi));".

Comment: Hmm, you're the first one who notices/mentiones it. Apparently there's more to it than i thought/imagined (the downside of being c(++) illiterate).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the child process's output to show up in a separate window. If so, you want to call `CreateProcess` and pass it the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag, rather than using `exec*`.